# Correlation function in polar coordinates

Tags: quantum-field-theory, coordinate-systems, fourier-transform, correlation-functions

I know that the Wightman correlation function is defined by $\langle 0|\hat{\Phi}(x)\hat{\Phi}(x')|0\rangle$ and it's expansion leads to an explicit expression depending from the commutator $[\hat{a}_k, \hat{a}_p^{\dagger}]$ which is $$\int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{\hbar}{2\omega_p}\exp{[-i\omega_p(t-t') + i\vec{p}\cdot(\vec{x}-\vec{x}')]}$$
This comes from having expanded the field in plane wave modes $u_p \sim \exp{[-i\omega_p t + i\vec{p}\cdot\vec{x}]}$. If I want instead expand the field in polar coordinates, knowing the system has a spherical symmetry and thus the angular variables could be integrated away in the mode expansion leaving a factor of $4\pi$, i.e.$\hat{\Phi}(x) = \int_0^{\infty}\frac{dk}{2\pi^2}k^2\sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{2k}}(\hat{a}_k u_k + \hat{a}_k^{\dagger}u_k^*)$ I can choose the $u_k= e^{-i\omega_k t}\frac{\sin{kr}}{kr}$ (expansion in the zeroth Bessel function). Now the Wightman correlation function would be something like $$\int \frac{dp p^2}{(2\pi)^2}\frac{\hbar}{2\omega_p}\exp{[-i\omega_p(t-t')]}\frac{\sin{pr}}{pr}\frac{\sin{pr'}}{pr'}$$ This expression seems suspicious to me, as it is lost any spatial translational symmetry. This is reflected in some paradoxical results (that I can show in a second moment if you want). Where am I wrong? What does the expansion in Bessel function kill concretely to change this expression?